# Finding the positions of an array index where a condition is met

Tags: javascript

I'm new to ES6 and am trying to learn how to write a function that finds the first array index number where there are most 0s together - e.g.:

```
var arr = [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0] // should return index 3
var arr = [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0] // should return index 8
var arr = [0,0,1,0] // should return index 0
```

Not sure why, but my attempt just returns an empty array rather than an array with the indexes where the numbers change from 0s to 1s:

```
var arr = [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0];
function amounts(c, i, arr) {
    var zeros = 0, onesTogether = 0, where = [], changes = 0, longest0s;

    if (c === 0 && arr[i+1] === 0 || c === 0 && arr[i-1] === 0) {
        zeros++;
    } else {
        longest0s = zeros;
        zeros = 0;
        changes++;
        where.push[i];
    }

    console.log('longest0s: ' + longest0s + '. changes: ' + changes + '. where: ' + where);
    return where;

}
arr.reduce(amounts);
```

I've got no idea how to find the index of the start of where there are most 0s together, but can't discover why the array is empty. Any ideas?

This should return array of [2,6,7]

```
[0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]
```

Comment: Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Comment: Try to `console.log` in the else clause: does it even fire? Also `where` is a reserved keyword, try using another variable name like `position` instead.

Comment: @NielsdeBruin where is not reserved word in javascript

Comment: `c` can't be zero when you are returning an array in callback....will be array on next iteration. Study how `reduce()` works more closely. If you want to reduce to array should be providing array as start value. Arguments are incorrect also for `reduce()`

Comment: @Rainmx93 huh you're right, I figured it was. Sorry about that. Comes down to preference then but I would avoid using such functional words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General idea: find the longest 0s substring and check its index.

You can try with:

```js
const find = arr => {
  const str = arr.join('');
  const longest = str.split(1).reduce((a, b) => a.length > b.length ? a : b);
  return str.indexOf(longest);
}

console.log(find([0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0])); // 3
console.log(find([0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0])); // 8
console.log(find([0,0,1,0])); // 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use two helper objects `last` and `result` with properties for `index` and `count` and update counter or reset the `last` object.

```js
function getIndex(array) {
    var last,
        result;

    array.forEach((v, i) => {
        if (v) {
            last = undefined;
            return;
        }
        last = last || { count: 0, index: i };
        last.count++;
        if (!result || result.count < last.count) {
            result = last;
        }
    });
    return result.index;
}

console.log(getIndex([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0])); // 3
console.log(getIndex([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])); // 8
console.log(getIndex([0, 0, 1, 0])); // 0
```